# In Boomla, how can I easily find the next sibling of a file

Tags: boomla

I'm quite used to `nextSibling`and `nextElementSibling` in the DOM. Is there an easy way of doing a similar thing with Boomla files?

I would need the next sibling within the same placeholder (and null if this is the last), but I'd be interested about finding the next sibling in *any* placeholder (and null if this is the last file in the last placeholder).

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no built-in method for this.

Here are 2 methods for the `sjs-4` engine for getting the next in the placeholder or parent:

```
var nextInBucket = function(f) {
    var bucket = f.bucketId();
    var bucketSiblings = f.query("../:" + bucket);
    var path = f.path();

    var index = 0;
    var found = false;
    bucketSiblings.each(function(t) {
        if (t.path() == path) {
            found = true;
            return false;
        }

        index++;
    });

    if ( ! found) {
        return null;
    }

    return bucketSiblings.eq(index + 1);
}
```

```
var nextInParent = function(f) {
    var parentChildren = f.query("../*");
    var path = f.path();

    var index = 0;
    var found = false;
    parentChildren.each(function(t) {
        if (t.path() == path) {
            found = true;
            return false;
        }

        index++;
    });

    if ( ! found) {
        return null;
    }

    return parentChildren.eq(index + 1);
}
```